# (SOLVED - partial) Flashing Source Built ROM Fails in TWRP, Invalid File Format

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, nexus-6p, aosp

I am new to the development community and have started to learn about building Android from source.  I've successfully built AOSP from source for my Nexus 6P (aosp_angler-userdebug, android-7.1.1_r14).  `$make` runs fine and I can install system.img and boot.img via fastboot and all is well.

However, the .zip made from `$make updatepackage` fails when I try to flash it in TWPR, throwing an error `Failed to install, invalid zip file format!`

After doing some research I noted that `$make updatepackage` isn't producing a META-INF folder.  When I run `$make dist`, META-INF is created and I can then `$./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files.zip out/target/dist/ota_update.zip`, but that ota_update.zip fails with the same error message in TWRP.

Comment: AFAIK AOSP doesn't natively have a way to package it into a functional flashable zip, that part is what 3rd-party ROMs do in their own ways (they should have a script or sth).

Comment: Thanks Andy.  That does seem to be the case.  Most have a META-INF and an AnyKernel (or similar) scrip to make things work.  It seems like the ota zips are fore side loading.